# Create a triangle view in swift that clips to the edges

Tags: swift, swift4, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to create two separate triangle views. The left side triangle is white and the right side is black.

I need both triangle views to be user interactable but since I am using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer to create the triangle the whole view is still covering the other triangle so the user cannot tap on the other triangle because the left side triangle is still covering the right side triangle.

I have a tap gesture on both triangles that print out different names but the triangle that gets added last is the only one that prints even if the other triangle is clicked.

I've tried adding clipsToBounds to the view and masksToBounds to the layer of the view but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way to accomplish this or do I need to head in a new direction?

[image]

Comment: How about using one single view to do this? This view will accept all touch events, and you will determine which triangle is tapped by looking at the touch point.

Comment: @Sweeper I am going to have a UIScrollView on each triangle though, so I will need each triangle to swipe independently to go through pages. In a way, I could do what you said by tracking the swipe on the holder view but I would like each triangle to work independently. Do you have any other ideas?